How to route to these pages with buttons of same props?
I am trying to route four buttons of same props to different routes in react but it is not working. I already created the routes, tried to use use Navigate but it didn't work.
     import React, {useState} from "react";
         import classes from "../classes";
    
function Card(props) {
         const [click, setClick] = useState("/")
            const activeButton = document.querySelector (".btn");
            const handleClick = () => {
             switch   (activeButton){
             case classes.id1:
          setClick ("jss-1-record")
          break;
          case classes.id2:
          setClick ("jss-2-record")
          break;
          case classes.id3:
          setClick ("jss-1-record")
          break;
          case classes.id4:
          setClick ("jss-2-record")
        
          default:
          setClick ("Page-Structure")
             }
          }
    
      return (
        
          <div className="container">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="top">
                <img className="circle-img" src={props.img} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="bottom">
              <button className="btn" onClick= {() =>{click && handleClick }}>
          <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        </button> 
    
           </div>
         </div>
          </div>
      );
      }
    export default Card; 



Besides a few grammar/typo mistakes, at first you mentioned "probs" - I guess you meant to write "props" as you have mentioned it later on? Overall I'm wondering why you even mentioned that since props is not used in the code? 2. Is your code in this question identical to your real code since it has syntax errors where you are missing a colon (:) after each case classes.id1 requires : on the end, could that be the issue? If not, do you have any errors in your console? If yes, then edit your post.


you don't need that, you need understand the props power.
function Card(props) {
    // imported from react-router-dom
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    // imported from react-router-dom
    const location = useLocation()
    
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Use the virtual router for reassign location
    navigate(props.path)
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="top">
          <img className="circle-img" src={props.img} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
            {/* if location path is the same of the card props.path add active class for trigger it in your css */}
          <button className={`btn ${location.path === props.path && "active"}`} onClick={handleClick}>
            <h2>{props.name}</h2>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function ParentComponent() {
    //define your props in the parent 
const btnProps = [
    {name:"btn1", path: "/", img:"https://url-or-src"},
    {name:"btn2", path: "/blog", img:"https://url-or-src"},
    {name:"btn3", path: "/article", img:"https://url-or-src"},
    {name:"btn4", path: "/comment", img:"https://url-or-src"}
]
    return (
        // react fragment <> for wrap many element without use div 
        <>
        <h1>Exemple parent title</h1>
        {btnProps.map((btnProp, index) =>  <Card key={index} props={btnProp}/>)}
        </>
      );
    
}

    

ideally, elements like your card should only render and interpret its props, which are distributed by the parent, so your component is reusable.
I think you've tried to target the active button.
Some libraries can do this for you, and react-router-dom's  component offers native tracking of the active button, which in your case is probably a better solution, if it's some kind of menu or navbar.
